# Finding gaps and overlaps in same feature class with Data Reviewer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, slivers, data-reviewer

I am trying to find gaps and overlaps in the same feature class (e.g. political boundary) with Data Reviewer.

The check I am using is Polygon Overlap/Gap Is Sliver (Feature on Feature Checks), and it requires me input 2 feature classes in the check window, so I input the political boundary in the Feature Class 1 and input it again in Feature Class 2.

Is this the right way or procedure?

[image]

Comment: My feeling is that there are relatively few Data ReViewer users, and so to try and attract a potential answerer, I think you will need to describe precisely the steps that you perform and an unexpected result from those steps (if you get one) rather than just asking "Is this the right way or procedure?".  I recommend not thinking about GIS SE as being some sort of online GIS tutor.  Don't forget to take the [Tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.